# How do I stop jsdom auto-qualifying href results when using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-selectors, jsdom

This script uses jsdom and jquery to get the value of an a tag's href attribute. For some reason it comes out fully qualified, relative to the path I'm running the script in. How can I get *just* the href value, not fully qualified?

```
var currentDoc = jsdom.jsdom('<html><head><title>href test</title></head><body><p><a href="test.html">Test</a></p></body></html>';, null, {});
var window = currentDoc.createWindow();
jsdom.jQueryify(window, 'jquery-1.4.2.min.js' , function() {
    console.log(window.$('a')[0]['href']);
});
```

(code snippet also at https://gist.github.com/2355968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `getAttribute` instead of just the field accessor.

```
var someLink = document.createElement("A");
someLink.href = "/foo";
someLink.href; // => "http://whatever.com/foo"
someLink.getAttribute("href"); // => "/foo"
```